# React Native Input component takes ony numeric values

Tags: validation, react-native, numeric, input-field

In React-Native project, I have an Input component from Native Base and I want to this component to take only numeric values 0-9 and give this field default value, I looked for other questions about this issue, I do not know maybe those answers are for 'textInput' component or somehow suggestions did not work for me?
Can you help me please?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946793/react-native-textinput-that-only-accepts-numeric-characters

Answer (score 16):

try use

```
keyboardType="numeric"
```

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype)

Comment: Unfortunately that can still allow non-numeric input to get in, such as commas and dashes depending on the platform.

Answer (score 4):

I grab your problem there is no attribute for Text Input to take numeric only. But I have two method for this, In first method you have to write the code for taking the value numeric this is hack but you can use it, the code is :

```
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.textInput}
          keyboardType = 'numeric'
          onChangeText = {(text)=> this.onChanged(text)}
          value = {this.state.myNumber}
        /> 

        onTextChanged(text) {
          // code to remove non-numeric characters from text
          this.setState({myNumber: text})
        }
```

[For second Method use this:](https://github.com/amirfl/react-native-num-textinput)

Answer (score 3):

```
keyboardType="number-pad"
```

see source https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype

Answer (score 2):

**You can use `keyboardType = 'numeric'` for numeric keyboard.**

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>Enter numeric value</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter number'}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={value => this.onChanged(value)}
          value={this.state.myNumber}
        />
      </View>
```

**In first case punctuation marks are included ex:- . and -**

**Use regular expression to remove punctuation marks.**

```
 onChanged(value) {

    this.setState({ myNumber: value.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '') });
  }
```

Please check snack link

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/1e004c