# React native onKeyPress is not working?

Tags: react-native

I have just placed TextInput `KeyboardType ={"numeric"}` just trying to find weather user enter '-' if means I have to `event.preventDefault()` in OnChange first.Later tried in onKeyPress but onKeyPress is not trigerring , I was just tried to do that but it allowing me to type shows warning Synthetic Event Performance issue.

guys help me .

Comment: on which platform you are testing?

Comment: are you testing with Android emulator?

Comment: Andriod no in mobile oly

Answer (score 10):

You are testing with android mobile whereas`onKeyPress` method is for `iOS`, check [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress) for same

You can use `onChangeText` for text change.

Example:

```
<TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onFirstNameText(text)}
    returnKeyType={'next'}
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    style={styles.inputColLeft}
/>
```

**Edit 2018**

`onKeyPress` is now also supported for Android devices as per [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/c9ff0bc212b680232f7379fba7b9332927075c3c).

From doc:

> **Note**: on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not
>   the hardware keyboard inputs.

Comment: not used yet, but do you need that?, to validate numbers only you can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946793/react-native-textinput-that-only-accepts-numeric-characters

Comment: onKeyPress now support Android.

Comment: For Android, it only support default keyboard, for non-default keyboard such as 'numeric', it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to this issue of synthetic event:

Input element:

```
<Input onKeyPress = {this.keyPress} />
```

keyPress function

```
keyPress = (event) => {

/* this line will solve your error */

event.persist();
console.log(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const App =()=>{
  const  handleKeyPress = ({ nativeEvent: { key: keyValue } }) => {
      console.log(keyValue);
      if(keyValue === 'Enter')
      {
        console.log("enter");
      }
  };
  return(
    <View>
         <TextInput
            placeholder="Your Password"
            placeholderTextColor="#666666"
            style={styles.inputSearch}
            // onEndEditing={(e)=>handleValidUser(e.nativeEvent.text)}
            onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
          />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onChangeText like this:

```
<TextInput  onChangeText = {(text) => this.getPhone(text)} keyboardType="numeric" autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false} onSubmitEditing={ () => this.addressInput.focus()} style={styles.input} placeholder="phone" placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.6)" underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0.0)" returnKeyType="next"/>

 getPhone = (text) => {
      this.setState({phone: text})
      //use your logic here 

   }
```