# In React native OnChange how to get Key code?

Tags: react-native

i want to check and restrict the number has decimal places.i won't allow like 90.90. for that i need a key code i have tried event.nativeEvent.Key but it producing undefined.

Comment: Change your approach. You can detect the new character and remove it. onChangeText will invoke a function, thats where you can perform something like this `(text) => text === '.' ? '' : text`. Just remember to notify your user (UX). For iOS, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress

Comment: You would need to filter the string with non allowed characters and set the state afterwards. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40803430/6109263
Or use: https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text