# React Native TextInput not updating when set state in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I am facing this issue in iOS, did same thing on this link [React Native TextInput that only accepts numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946793/react-native-textinput-that-only-accepts-numeric-characters)
 but did not slove in iOS deivce

changes by setting state not reflecting in TextInput, below is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  enteredMobile: '',
};}

onChanged(text){
    this.setState({
            enteredMobile: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
        });
  }
```

My Text Input

```
<TextInput
    placeholderTextColor="lightgrey"
    placeholder="Enter mobile no."
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
    maxLength={10}
    style={{height: 40,top:140, left :94,width:500, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onChanged(text)}
    value = {this.state.enteredMobile}
    />
```

You can see the updated one in the image below the table but its not updating TextInput itself.

[image]

Comment: Where's your textinput?. Can you highlight in your screenshot?

Comment: Below Mobile number "9910werdd"

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj You have to code using ES6 JS in `onChanged` function because sometime it will not work in ES5 syntax.

> Try this one

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        enteredMobile: '',
    };
}

onChanged = (text) => {
    this.setState({
            enteredMobile: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
        });
  }
```

My Text Input

```
<TextInput
    placeholderTextColor="lightgrey"
    placeholder="Enter mobile no."
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
    maxLength={10}
    style={{height: 40,top:140, left :94,width:500, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.onChanged(text)}
    value = {this.state.enteredMobile}
    />
```