# How to get ONLY number input when using numeric in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get ONLY number for input in react-native, i know if we want to get number, we can use `keyboardType="numeric"` ,but problem is, nothing can stop me from input `* + #`

Like below image, i still can iput these symbol without any problem
[image]

I search stackoverflow for this, but that answer was outdated, it was 2016 and that time, keyboard only have `.` symbol.

For 5 years later, i think maybe someone will get struggle like me, so if you solved this, please help, thank you a lots

Comment: Are you asking how to display a keyboard with only digits, or how to prevent any non-digits from being entered in the input? Those are very different things.

Comment: It will be nice if the keyboard display only digit, i thought it can't, so i was trying to prevent any non-digit being entered

Comment: The numeric show us both digits and symbol above, so i don't know what to do

Comment: You are right, the keyboard belongs to your phone so react-native has no control over it. You can use a number picker instead of a text input to allow only numbers. Or use a controlled input to with a regex like this `.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`.

Comment: Can you give me an example, i understand your idea, but i have no idea how to apply this

Comment: There's tones of examples... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751269/5708566